# How to draw a thin grey dotted border in CSS?

Tags: css

Hey so I'm taking a computer science class on web development but I'm having a hard time with this one part of my assignment. How would I draw a thin, dotted grey border in CSS? I was thinking of writing in CSS:

```css
div {
  border: thin dotted;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

But I don't think that's right.

Comment: your code works fine

Answer (score 1):

An important part of practical Computer Science is to learn how to consult documentation.  I find the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) to be a pretty decent reference for CSS properties.  The MDN page for the [`border` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) provides the following example:

```
/* width | style | color */
border: medium dashed green;
```

Which means you can likely achieve your style by using something like:

```
border: 1px dotted #CCC;
```

Answer (score 0):

`div { border: 1px dotted #ccc; }`

The `#ccc` is hexidecimal for gray.
For all shades of gray use `000` through `999` and `AAA` through `FFF`. 0 is black and F is white

Comment: Wow, we both chose the exact same shade and representation of grey: `#CCC`

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark - They claim there's 50 shades of grey, though in reality there's actually 255 :)